# Deleting a local docker repo from the UI results in 405 Method not Not Allowed

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory Pro Version *4.11.0*

I m having issue with, deleting this specific repo ( a local docker repo ).
I m able to delete other local docker repos I create

Is there any other way/work around to  rename/remove this repo ?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSvl1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHzi0.png)

Comment: You should look at the Artifactory logs for errors. 4.11.0 is a very old version, and you should consider upgrading soon, both for security and support.

Comment: Thanks for the response, nothing in the logs both artifactory and acces logs,  yes we are due for upgrade sometime later